# Strawberry Perl version check

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl

I am very new to strawberry Perl and installed the strawberry Perl (strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit.msi) on my windows 2016 server.

After successful installation, I checked the version of the perl and it shows as below.

Please advise what I am missing to see the 5.32 version.

```
C:\Users\New_Learner\Documents>perl -v

This is perl 5, version 20, subversion 1 (v5.20.1) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

Copyright 1987-2014, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no other Perl installed?

Comment: This is the only perl version I just installed.

Comment: Where did you install it? Can you run it with the full path instead of just `perl`?

Comment: The installer at least gives the option to update the PATH. This update is probably not reflected in a console that was opened before the installation. Try reopening the console. If that fails, you simply need to fix up the PATH to find the appropriate installation of Perl (or use the full path to the appropriate `perl` when invoking it).

Comment: @ikegami This worked. I can see the installed version now. THANK YOU!!!